# Taking K'th element in BCT(Binary count Tree);

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-search-tree, josephus

The problem with the function is that after 1 calling of it, it doesn't work as it should. 
For example, for k = 4, and size of a tree n = 7, when called it should return firstly node with value of 4 then 5, when in reality it return node with value 4 and NULL pointer. Can not find solution for that.

I've been struggling with this function for quite some time, It takes node_t *root as a root of our tree and k as a k'th element. Our structure looks like it.

```
typedef struct node_t{
  struct node_t *left, *right, *up;
  node *key; // its just a node from linked list from which tree was created, so key -> value
  bool isVisited;
  int t; // number of subnodes + 1
}
```

our function should also decrease t on every node from root to designated node and change isVisited to true, so we don't visit it again.

```
node_t *nextK(node_t *root, int k){
    int leftSize = 0;
    if(root == NULL) return NULL;
    if(root -> left != NULL){
        leftSize = root -> left -> t;
    }
    if(k <= leftSize) {
        root -> t = root -> t - 1;
        return nextK(root -> left, k);
    }
    if(k == leftSize + 1 && root -> isVisited == false) {
        root -> isVisited = true;
        return root;
    }
    else{
        root -> t = root -> t - 1;
        return nextK(root -> right, k - leftSize);
    }
}
```

Example how our BCT is created from linked_list:

```
node_t *linkedListToBST(node *linked_list, node_t *root, node_t *temp){
    if(linked_list!=NULL) {
        node_t *new;
        new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        new -> isVisited = false;
        new -> up = root;
        new -> key = middle(linked_list);
        new -> right=linkedListToBST(new -> key -> next, new, temp);
        if(new-> key!=linked_list)
            new-> left= linkedListToBST(linked_list, new, temp);
        else{
            new-> left= linkedListToBST(NULL, new, temp);
        }
        new -> t= new -> right -> t + new -> left -> t +1;
        return new;
    }
    else{
        return temp;
    }
}
node_t *iniBST2(node_t *root, node *head){
    node_t sentinel;
    sentinel.t = 0;
    sentinel.left = &sentinel;
    sentinel.right = &sentinel;
    sentinel.up = &sentinel;
    node_t *new_root;
    new_root = linkedListToBST(head, root, &sentinel);
    return new_root;
}
```

```
void addFirst(node **head, int v) {
    node *new_head;
    new_head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_head->value = v;
    new_head->next = *head;
    *head = new_head;
}
int n = 7;
    for(int i = n; i > 0; i--){
        addFirst(&linked_list, i);
        if(i == n){
            tail = linked_list;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Why my function doesn't want to cooperate with me >:(

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Your post is not clear regarding whatever it is you need help with.  Please [edit] your post.

Comment: Added more specific description of a problem.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve].  I thought I spotted a hole in the code, but now I think I need to see your actual n=7 tree.

Comment: Edited my original post so it contains functions how our BCT is created, it is fully balanced.

Comment: And the seven nodes that repro the bug?

Comment: Added to post how I create these nodes.